# How can I convert from 'pathlib.WindowsPath to simple path for subprocess

Tags: python

I get error `TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable` when i try to execute this

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l', str(file)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Is there a way I can do it properly?

Comment: ` p = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l', str(file)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: What is `file`? Please post all the code necessary.